# How to use the integers 1 to n as a column when plotting a data file with Gnuplot?

Tags: bash, gnuplot

Let's assume I have  a file "data.dat" like this:

```
#Time          Velocity
1              24
1              26
1              28
```

Now, I need to plot column 2 in gnuplot. It has to be plotted over the natural numbers from 1 to n, so in this case from 1 to 3. In general I could use the following gnuplot with the following:

```
plot "data.dat" using 1:2
```

but I do not want to use column 1, but the numbers 1 to 3. How do I do that in a clever, gnuplot-internal way? If that is not possible, what is the best way using bash for adding a column that goes from 1 to 3 (after using sth. like `cat data.dat | awk '{ print $2 }' > new_data.dat` to column 2 from data.dat)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zeroth column, a pseudo-column, contains the row number (starting at 0):

```
plot "data.dat" using ($0 + 1):2
```